How to match range of dates using regular expressions
I have, for example, this date range sentence to test: from 10-08-2024 to 12-08-2024, I need to extract the dates.
I have used Regex101 site to design the regular expressing, getting this one:
^(from)\s((?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(?:0[1-9]|1[1,2])-(?:19|20)\d{2})\s(to)\s((?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(?:0[1-9]|1[1,2])-(?:19|20)\d{2})$
It works, however, all are returned as groups instead of matches.

as you see, start and end dates are returned as groups. The only match is the whole sentence.
How can I get the dates to be returned as match 2 and match 3 instead of group 2 and group 4, respectively?
Thanks
Jaime

Something like this?

What language are you using? (?<=^from\s)(?:(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(?:0[1-9]|1[1,2])-(?:19|20)\d{2})|\s+(?<=to\s)(?:(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(?:0[1-9]|1[1,2])-(?:19|20)\d{2})$?

You can use positive lookbehind to check (from|to) followed by the date regex that you have provided.
(?<=(?:from|to)\s*)(?:(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(?:0[1-9]|1[1,2])-(?:19|20)\d{2})

Demo
Here you get your dates as match 1 and match 2.
Sample source:


const regex = /(?<=(?:from|to)\s*)(?:(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(?:0[1-9]|1[1,2])-(?:19|20)\d{2})/gm;

const str = `from 10-08-2024 to 12-08-2024`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    m.forEach((match) => {
        console.log(match);
    });
}




If you literally want those strings to be separate matches you need to make two different match possibilities with the | alternation operator.
You could do:
(?<=from\s)((?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(?:0[1-9]|1[1,2])-(?:19|20)\d{2})|(?<=to\s)((?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(?:0[1-9]|1[1,2])-(?:19|20)\d{2})

Demo
If you just want a more sensible grouping, you could do:
^(?:from)\s((?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(?:0[1-9]|1[1,2])-(?:19|20)\d{2})\s(?:to)\s((?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(?:0[1-9]|1[1,2])-(?:19|20)\d{2})$

which give you two capture groups.
Demo

You're "matching" the entire line - the "from" and "to" included.  There's only one match.
The groups are the pieces you might want to pull out, depending on what you're intending to apply the regex with, you might reference the groups using \2 and \4 back-reference notation to get the actual dates.

You can use lookarounds and remove the capture groups. But there is a better way to do this, if your question had more context:
(?<=^from\s)(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(?:0[1-9]|1[1,2])-(?:19|20)\d{2}|(?<=\sto\s)(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(?:0[1-9]|1[1,2])-(?:19|20)\d{2}$

